# How can we use conductivity measurements of water to find hydrogen ion concentration of water?

Tags: water, physical-chemistry

How can we use conductivity measurements of water to find the hydrogen ion ($\mathrm{H}^+$) concentration in water?

Comment: For the question are you considering that H+ is the only cation? Or is your solution filled with an assortment of cations and anions.

Comment: It is pure water. No other ions are present.

Comment: hmmm...are you allowed just to use the pH and figure from there?

Comment: No, we want to find H+ ion concentration using the conductivity method. We want to find the pH using that.

Comment: Isn't that what a pH meter does?

Comment: Pure water has both hydrogen ions and hydroxide ions, under all conditions. You can use [conductivity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductivity_(electrolytic)) measurements to find the conductance of water, but it is extremely hard to do properly and you need the transport coefficients of hydrogen ions and hydroxide ions. Just getting pure water, knowing it is and keeping it pure, is extremely hard. Just a chemist’s perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is how I would do it, I would set up cathode and anode to measure the conductivity. I would then compare that to a buffer solution of known ph. If you can't find a buffer solution, see if there is a chart you can find of Hydrogen ion conductivity relationship to pH.(But then you may have to take in temperature of solutions).
http://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/EP0229038A2/imgb0001.png

Such as this, this will give you a relationship which you should be able to figure out from. You do know what "Molar" means? or to figure ppms?

Comment: If you can't find a buffer solution, see if there is a chart you can find of Hydrogen ion conductivity relationship to pH.(But then you may have to take in temperature of solutions).

Comment: Assume you do not have such a chart, you are the first person doing the expt.  Buffer conductivity is not only due to H+ ions so you can't compare them directly.

Comment: @OddharakTyagi, I added a chart of conductivity and concentrations.  But, I guess you are trying to figure it out from "scratch". My thought would be to work it back from your conductivity test. Look up the formulas, will deal with Ohms, possibly can figure from there.

Comment: Be careful . $H_2$ and $O_2$ will form. Clearly _that_ is outside the scope of Ohm's law.

Comment: How does this differ from a standard pH meter ?